# Organizing MVC2 Views with a subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

We have a fairly large MVC project with a large number of views and partial views (display/editor templates). Pretty much 95% of our UI is in our templates, our `aspx` views are just placeholders that call our `ascx` templates. As such, whenever we open that `Views` folder in VS2010, it's fairly painful to scroll down to the `Shared` folder for us to manage our templates.

We'd LIKE to change this hierarchy just a bit. Instead of having a folder for each controller under `Views`, instead we'd like to have a folder called `Pages` under `Views` and have our per-controller folders under here. This way, when we open `Views` we have 2 folders: `Pages` and `Shared`.

Is this easily possible without going back and editing every single one of our controllers where they simply `return View();` to `return View("Pages/MyControllerName/MyActionHandler");`? I'd like the controllers to still simply `return View();` and without my URLs changing. So in other words, I just want to move my root directory for my Views into Views/Pages, but not for templates - they stay as they are.

---

Solution we went with:

**global.asax.cs:** (add these as the first 2 lines of `Application_Start()` - change nothing else)

```
        var locations = ((WebFormViewEngine)ViewEngines.Engines.First()).ViewLocationFormats.ToList().Select(x => x.ToLower().Replace("views/{", "Views/Pages/{"));

        ((WebFormViewEngine) ViewEngines.Engines.First()).ViewLocationFormats = locations.ToArray();
```

This allows our `Views` folder to have 3 things in it:

1. Pages
2. Shared
3. web.config

Since we do 95% of our UI work within our `Shared` `DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates`, this rmeoves the mostly-ignorable stuff from being in-our-face all the time as developers. While the suggested answer was to do `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();` and then add a newly-instantiated one, we had problems with MVC playing nice with the new one. So we chose to instead alter the functional and already-instantiated instance. I don't like the casting, and we'll put some code around that to be better, but this is the functional code to get anybody started that also wants to do this.

Comment: Just so you know. Instead of dropping everything in the Shared folder you can put controller-specific templates in a EditorTemplates or DisplayTemplates subfolder. Example: /Views/[ControllerName]/EditorTemplates

Comment: Hmm, good to know! Not sure that we want to organize them this way as we organize our ASPX files along with our UI Navigational hierarchy but we organize our ASCX files along our entity model organizational structure and the two aren't even close to one another. However, that's a great tip that I was unaware of!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a ViewEngine with the `ViewLocationFormats` property set to include your new locations.

Comment: Am I able to re-register the default ViewEngine? We're not using Razor, we're using whatever the default one is. Sorry, this is a bit new to me.

Comment: Remove the `WebFormsViewEngine` from `ViewEngines.Engines`, then add a new instance.

Comment: Don't see a ViewPaths property on there or any obvious alternative. `ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); var engine = new WebFormViewEngine(); engine.XXXXXXX????; ViewEngines.Engines.Add(engine);` Also, I'm failing at being a Google user, apparently. :-/

Comment: Oh, wait, I think it's the ViewLocationFormats that I want?

Comment: `{0}` is the view name; `{1}` is the controller

Comment: Yup, I think I know what needs done to get this part functional. Anything I need to consider with the web.config that is in the Views folder? Any need to reproduce something similar in my new `Pages` folder? I assume not as the existing one will still apply...

Comment: As long as it's a subfolder, it will inherit all of the parent `Web.config`

Comment: .... AND of course, TFS crashed after it had moved ~50% of my ASPX files. I think I'm good. Will update this when I'm finished but I think I'm going to need to undo and start this operation from scratch, so it'll be a few more minutes.

Comment: So ultimately, I decided to just manipulate the existing ViewEngine's ViewLocationFormats property rather than throwing it away and creating a new one (it wasn't liking that so much). I'll post the solution in the question. Thanks for the help!